# Python 2.7 with Spyder 3.0

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I installed Spyder 3.0 and also python 2.7. I want to run python 2.7 codes with spyder 3.0
I tried to change python interpreter in spyder preferences. "Preferences->Python Interpreter-> Use the following Python interpreter". I chose Python 2.7 but it did not work. I also searched Python 2.7 executable file but I could not find it in the location usr/bin (ubuntu 18.04).
How can deal with this problem?

Comment: to which python installation did you install spyder? why spyder 3.0 specifically?

Comment: I tried to install Spyder 2 and installed it but it did not launched interestingly. I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have some codes in Python 2.7 and I want to run them in spyder 3.

Comment: You will have to use Spyder 2. And it should be available from the Software Center. Alternatively, you should be able to call `python2.7 -m pip install spyder` from a terminal - maybe with the `--user` option to keep the system installation clean. Or even cleaner, use a virtual environment.

Comment: In the software center Spyder 2.0 is not available, only spyder 3.0 is in there. I installed spyder 2 from terminal but it did not work. In the net it says it is possible to run python 2.7 codes with spyder 3 but Python interpreter should be changed with way that I described above. But I could not find the executable file.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder installation is specific to one version of Python.

1) install python 2.7

2) run `python2.7 -m pip install spyder` in cmd

3) you should find spyder in `C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\Scripts\spyder.exe` (for Windows at 
least)

4) You can make a shortcut of it

you should see the python version in the Spyder window title

Comment: Thank you for your help but the path which is given by you is for Windows, I use ubuntu 18.04. By the way I think I  took care of it.